# How to use keyboard shortcuts to access MS Office 2013 QAT (Quick Access Toolbar) shortcuts using an Azerty keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office

In MS Office 2010, keyboard shortcuts for the Quick Access Toolbar were immediate, even with a Azerty keyboard : ALT + [&] key (1 in CAPS)  --> means ALT+1 --> first icon in the QAT

In MS Office 2013, keyboard shortcuts for the Quick Access Toolbar does not work anymore in an easy & efficient way : 
must do ALT (wait) then SHIFT+1 --> too slow !

Another question deals with [custom one-key keyboard shortcuts](https://superuser.com/questions/203294/custom-one-key-keyboard-shortcuts-in-outlook-2010-or-2013) using AutoHotkey, but I am in a big company where I cannot customize my standard laptop at all. I cannot install any 3rd party application.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but it is not optimal: by using <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, the shortcut works correctly.

Obviously this is not ideal if I want to write after some text.